# Angular pushing an array of an user object into a subject

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developping a single app and at the moment the only good behavior is that I'm getting an user from an API with HttpClient method.
The method is store in a service.

Getting the user is a success but now I want to get a specific array from that user to re-use it by my will.

Should I make another service since this value will be use in 2 components ?
How should I procced to get this array in a var ?

Exemple of user object :

```
{
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  arrayIWant: []
}
```

My user is in a subject and here is the way I use it in a component

```
  user: User;
  userSubscription: Subscription;


  constructor(
    public userService: UserService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userSubscription = this.userService.userSubject.subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
      }
    );
    this.userService.getSingleUserFromServer();
    this.userService.emitUser();
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.userSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Should I put this code in every component where I want to use the user or is there a way to definie globaly the user ?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is here. If multiple components want to get access to a single user object, then it would make sense to cache the user in the user service.

Comment: I think going with a BehaviourSubject instead of a Subject would allow you to "store"  that variable in your service. And would eliminate the need to have it in every component

Comment: add a public variable to the service and assign the array to this varible on success of api call. Since each service only has once instance you can access it everywhere by importing this service. Make sure the service is provided in root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [BehaviourSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) which will hold the last value of whatever that service populates the userSubject with

```
public userSubject: BehaviourSubject<User> = new BehaviourSubject(null);

getSingleUserFromServer(): void { 
   //get your user from http
   userSubject.next(result);
}
```

In you HTML you can use the async pipe to display the values of the inner array you want. Or just use it in your component by subscribing to the last emission of the behaviourSubject

```
//X.Component
public subscriptionKiller: Subject<void> = new Subject();
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.userSubject
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.subscriptionKiller))
        .subscribe((lastUser: User) => {
        someMethod(this.userService.userSubject.value.arrayIWant);
    }
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptionKiller.next()
}
```

Comment: It's correct but I actually had the same behavior. My problem came from the async. How can I define a value from something asynchronus ?

Comment: If you are using async pipe in your html you can unwrap the value doing `(this.userService.userSubject | async).value`